# How to make a box like this

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, tikz-styles, frame-title, titling

Please how can I make something like this in LaTeX. Kindly, help.[image]

Comment: This looks very much like one of the (ugly) chapter header style provided by `fncychap`, in particular Glenn.

Answer (score 4):

@egreg's comment -- that loading the `fncychap` package with the option `Glenn` gets the job done -- is correct.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand\chaptername{Tutorial Questions}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} %just for this example
\chapter{Tutorial III}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways, depending on your desired use. Here is a possibility with Ti*k*Z.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{my label/.style={fill=white, align=left, inner sep=2pt, above=3pt, font={\small}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[thick] (0,1)node[my label, right=-3pt]{\sffamily TUTORIAL QUESTIONS {\large 3}} 
    rectangle (10,0)node[my label, left=-3pt]{TUTORIAL III};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```